# Является ли данная программа, по нахождению самой частой цифры, эффективной по времени и памяти? И как это определить?

Tags: python, алгоритм, time-complexity

Дан набор из N целых положительных чисел. Необходимо определить, какая цифра чаще всего встречается в десятичной записи чисел этого набора. Если таких цифр несколько, необходимо вывести наибольшую из них.

Напишите эффективную по времени и по памяти программу для решения этой задачи.

Программа считается эффективной по времени, если при увеличении количества исходных чисел N в k раз время работы программы увеличивается не более чем в k раз.

Программа считается эффективной по памяти, если память, необходимая для хранения всех переменных программы, не превышает одного килобайта и не увеличивается с ростом N.

```
a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
N=int(input()) 
k=0 
g=0 
for i in range(N): 
     r=int(input()) 
     while r>0: 
     b=r%10 
     a[b]=a[b]+1 
     r=r//10 
for i in range (len(a)): 
     if a[i]>=k: 
     k=a[i] 
     g=i 
print(g)
```

Comment: Да, является. вы проходите по числу один раз, каждый раз анализируя только 1 разряд. значит зависимость по времени линейна. И массив на 10 элементов явно влезает в 1 килобайт. Только ваша программа не соответствует тексту задачи, там вроде сказано, что вводятся массив целых чисел, а вы вводите только одно число

Comment: В а[] должно быть 10 элементов, а не 9. Сейчас программа вылетит при первой же девятке в числе.

Comment: Отступы надо бы поправить.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа линейная по времени (`O(n)`) (в предположении фиксированной ширины чисел) и O(1) по памяти. То есть согласно приведённым критериям, она эффективна по времени и памяти.

По сути она равнозначна:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Counter

numbers = (int(input()) for _ in range(int(input())))
digit_counts = Counter(digit for n in numbers for digit in str(n)).items()
print(max(digit_counts, key=lambda d_c: (d_c[1], d_c[0]))[0])
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/G00YVv).

Вместо `Counter` достаточно список использовать (как в коде в вопросе): `digits = [0] * 10` (подобная запись легче позволяет ошибки избежать в числе нулей).

Словами алгоритм:

- указанное число раз читаем (лениво) числа, получаем `numbers` генератор
- считаем сколько раз цифры встречаются во вводе, получаем `digit_counts` генератор пар: `(digit, count) == (цифра, сколько раз она встретилась)`
- находим наибольшую цифру, среди самых часто встречаемых цифр (то есть критерий сравнения сперва по `count`, затем по величине цифры `digit`).